# C# MVC/API Custom Validation Trigger - One Field Only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

I have a single field for an API model that I want custom validation for through whatever method possible.

The solution I need is: **On modelstate validation fail for that specific field - I want to run custom code to modify the value of that field.**

---

Due to the codebase I'm working with some constraints:

The validation trigger code has to be inside the model or bound to it somehow.

It's not reasonable for me to create custom validator for the entire model.

It's not reasonable for me to put code in controller on `!modelstate.valid`

Comment: I found the solution for this I will post the answer as soon as I complete the work.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I didn't think you could mix and match annotations with custom validation. You can.

Make your class inherit IValidateableObject

```
public class MyClass : IValidateableObject
{
}
```

Add Validate Method - "FieldName" is your class variable being validated

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
     if(your_condition_is_invalid)
     {
          yield return new ValidationResult(
              errorMessage: "your error message", 
              memberNames: new[] { "FieldName" } 
          );
     }
}
```

Below not applicable to this problem specific problem but I thought to include incase there is a frontend component.

The downside is, according to the person I asked, if you are using for a webapp, there are cases where you need to write custom frontend validation.

It doesn't automatically mesh with default mvc frontend validation / jquery unobtrusive.

If you plan to do this for an app where you have strict frontend validation standards then be ready to write a validator for that field.